# Why does my code keep displaying error resolving onAction event handler when launched?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I am just starting tutorials on JavaFx properties and I keep receiving the error below when running my code.

> javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#addAction',
> either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error
> in the script.
> /C:/Users/user/eclipse-workspace/JavaFXBeans/bin/application/Main.fxml:15

I have linked the MainController with the SceneBuilder and also linked the ActionEvent to the Button on SceneBuilder, yet I keep receiving the same error code.

Below is a snippet of the fxml code:

```
<Button layoutX="98.0" layoutY="192.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#addAction" prefHeight="34.0" prefWidth="86.0" text="++" textFill="RED">
    <font>
        <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
    </font>      
</Button>
```

(onAction="#addAction") is underlined red in the above code.

Below is a snippet of the MainController that shows my method:

```
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    numObj.setmyNum(0);
    numObj.intMethod().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() { 
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Object> arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) { 
            lblStatus.setText(new Integer(numObj.getmyNum()).toString());           
            
        }
        

    public final void addAction(ActionEvent event) {
        numObj.setmyNum(numObj.getmyNum());
    }
```

Why doesn't my .fxml file find that method?

Comment: We can't tell you why code we don't know and which you didn't show us produces an error.

Comment: Please add your code; it will help you to get a better and quicker answer :)

Comment: OH GOD SPIDERS and Reg, I have added the codes. What do you think is causing the error?

Comment: The reference in the fxml needs to be to an existing method in your controller. So you need to show your controller with the method `public void addAction(ActionEvent event)`. Why do you think the initialize method you have pasted is relevant at all? It really appears you just pasted some random code.

Comment: The method public void addAction(ActionEvent event) is present in my controller. Is there another way to reference it?

Comment: I see you have a `public final void addAction(ActionEvent event)` in an anonymous class in the initialize method. There is no way the fxml loader would know to look that up. You need to move that to a method in your controller itself.

Comment: "The method public void addAction(ActionEvent event) is present in my controller." You need to show that.

Comment: I have been struggling with this error for almost 5 hours now, hence the reason I pasted the initialize method, peradventure an error is there. lol. I'm getting frustrated.

Comment: Thanks matt. My code is running properly after moving  it to the controller itself as you said.

Comment: [mcve] is required __always__ for debugging questions - there is too much that can possibly go wrong, particularly (though certainly not only :) with lesser experinced coders. Without there's nothing to do but playing guessing games which have some charm but at the end of the day are a waste of time for all. Also for future readers - who are at the focus of this site! - if there is no clear problem statement (with [mcve]! - rubbing in) it's less probable that they find the answer, even if it's good.

Comment: curious: from which tutorial do you learn? Naturally, everything that can be wrong/misunderstood sooner or later will go wrong/misunderstood .. the human brain is very creative .. but: assuming a method in a changelistener (its existence in itself is far from usual trails) can be found by loading/wiring mechanism is .. a extremely big stretch :)

Comment: Why did you edit the question so the cause of the problem is no longer visible?

Comment: @James_D good catch :) reverted

Answer (score 2):

When you have an fxml and an associated controller,

```
fx:controller="org.openjfx.FxmlTestController"
```

Then you can reference methods of that controller with #methodName. For your example **we can only assume** your controller is named `MainController` then your `onAction` declaration.

```
onAction="#addAction"
```

That means you should have a method in your main controller with the signature `public void addAction(ActionEvent event)`.

> Below is a snippet of the MainController:

When you say something like this, it really helps to say "why" you're including this bit. As somebody with pretty good grasp of basic knowledge about javafx and fxml, I did not think to look at the change listener for a method named "addAction"

Maybe something like.

> Below is a snippet of the MainController that shows my method `public void addAction(ActionEvent event)`. Why doesn't my .fxml file find that method?

Glad to hear you got it working.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I'm still learning everything about this, so I truly appreciate your corrections.